# Is there a significant difference between two expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm wondering if there is a difference between using a Lambda expression and the delegate anonymous keyword type.  Is one preferred over the other?  From what I've seen both seem to be interchangeable.

```
public delegate void SomeDel(string input);

public class myClass
{

   private ObjWithDel myObj;

   public myClass()
   {
    // Lambda Case
     myObj.DoDel += (val)=>{textbox1.Text = val;}

    // delegate keyword case
     myObj.DoDel += delegate(string val){textbox1.Text = val;}

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The two are different: a lambda is an "anonymous" method, it doesn't have a permanent name, whereas a Delegate is actually a reference to a method or lambda.
Most of the time, lambdas will be faster than delegates, but there's cases where you can only use delegates or lambdas, not the two.

Comment: OP is not asking about the difference between a lambda and a delegate, but rather about the difference between the two syntaxes to create an anonymus method and obtain a delegate holding it. As it happens, there is no difference at runtime. Your statement that a lambda is faster than a delegate makes no sense.